# Getting ZuulException while running Jmeter load test

Tags: docker, jmeter, microservices

Getting 500, internal server error, ZuulException, message: "GENERAL"

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 500 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

So you need to look into your server logs in order to determine the failure reason.

If the error occurs only under a higher load and doesn't occur when the load is lower or with 1 user most probably it indicates that your server is overloaded and hence cannot properly respond to the JMeter requests.

Checklist:

- Again logs: your application specific logs, any middleware logs (application server, database, load balancer, etc.)
- Ensure that your application is properly configured for high loads, normally default configuration is applicable only for development and very low loads, for the high loads everything needs to be properly tuned, i.e. see [Optimizing web servers for high throughput and low latency](https://dropbox.tech/infrastructure/optimizing-web-servers-for-high-throughput-and-low-latency) generic article followed by queries "your component here performance tuning" for each component being used
- Make sure that the application under test has enough capacity to operate in terms of hardware resources (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.) as it might be as simple as lack of RAM or something like this. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for this purpose if there are no better tools installed/available like an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tool
- re-run your test with a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled, it should give you insights regarding what's going on under the hood when you run the load test, i.e. slowest functions/ heaviest DB queries, largest objects, et.c